# Kotlin Desktop Compose Does Not Refresh Main View

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

Every time I click on a tile in my board it should refresh the `MainView()` so a red border can be on the tile, but it doesn't refresh the view. Is there any way to update the view every time the `board` changes?

Application Start:

```
var board: Board = Board()

fun main() = application {
    board = Board()

    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, title = "Castle Run" ) {
        WindowContent(::exitApplication)
    }
}
```

UI:

```
@Composable
fun FrameWindowScope.WindowContent(onExit: () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme {
        MainView() { tile -> click(tile) }
    }
}

fun click(tile: Tile){
    board.selectTile(tile)
    println(board.selectedTile)
}

@Composable
fun MainView(onClick: (Tile) -> Unit) {
    paintBoard(onClick)
}

@Composable
fun paintBoard(onClick: (Tile) -> Unit) {
    for (r in 0 until board.rows + 2) {
        for (c in 0 until board.columns + 2) {
            paintTile(board.boardArray[r][c], board.getPieceAt(r, c), onClick)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles. If this doesn't help, include `Board` code

Comment: Thanks homie I would've never found the tutorial if it wasn't for you. Now I'm using board as a mutable state and it is working great.